Parameters cannot be changed with Scenario Manager

I am a beginner in OMNet++ and I have created a multi-node network using OMNET++ INET framework. The nodes are instances of WirelessHosts. I am trying chaange their mobility parameters using Scenario Manager. But I am getting a runtime error like above, Please guide me to fix this issue.

To fix this, I added @mutable property to the Network Description (.ned) file of LinearMobility under inet/mobility/single/. In order to change the parameters during runtime, the parameter should be mutable. Mutable parameters can be set to a different value during runtime

Beware. You just turned off the error message. There is a reason why @mutable was not in the NED file. The reason is that the underlying LinearMobility code does NOT handle the parameter change events. So you can change now the parameter value, but that will not change the behavior of the model at all.
Parameters may be changed during runtime only if:

they are declared volatile and the underlying c++ code does not cache them (i.e. they are always acessed using par("name")
there is a properly written handleParameterChange() method that deals with any parameter change during runtime.

